# Поиск и визуализация кратчайшего пути между вершинами графа

Tags: python, matplotlib, графы, networkx

У меня есть граф, допустим, из пяти вершин. 
И мне нужно найти кратчайший путь из одной вершины в другую по Алгоритму Флойда-Уоршела.
Но проблема вот в чем:
Мне нужно покрасить этот путь в другой цвет в графе.
А для этого мне нужен список всех ребер которые входят в кратчайший путь. 
То есть, мне нужно получить вот такой список: `result = [[0, 2], [2, 1]]`

Пример на фото:

[image]

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе матрицу смежности графа в виде текста/CSV ?

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем использовать алгоритм Флойда-Уоршела если искать нужно кратчайший путь для пары вершин?? Этот алгоритм предназначен для поиска кратчайших путей между __всеми__ парами вершин графа

Comment: @MaxU знаю, но преподаватель хочет, чтобы еще в графе показался другим цветом путь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне данная задача показалась интересной и поэтому я решил сделать рабочий пример, который,  возможно, окажется полезным будушим посетителям SO.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_weighted_edges_from([
    ('s', 'u', 10), ('s', 'x', 5), ('u', 'v', 1), ('u', 'x', 2), 
    ('v', 'y', 1), ('x', 'u', 3), ('x', 'v', 5), ('x', 'y', 2), 
    ('y', 's', 7), ('y', 'v', 6)])

# расчет кратчайших путей для ВСЕХ пар вершин
predecessors, _ = nx.floyd_warshall_predecessor_and_distance(G)
# кратчайший путь от вершины [s] к вершине [v]
shortest_path_s_v = nx.reconstruct_path('s', 'v', predecessors)
# список ребер кратчайшего пути
edges = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(shortest_path_s_v, shortest_path_s_v[1:])]
# список всех весов ребер
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
# позиции вершин для визуализации графа
#pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
# рисуем граф
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
# рисуем веса ребер
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=weights)
# рисуем кратчайший путь: [s] -> [v]
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist=edges, edge_color="r", width=3)
# заголовок графика
title = "Shortest path between [{}] and [{}]: {}"\
        .format("s", "v", " -> ".join(shortest_path_s_v))
plt.title(title)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное!!! Мне очень помогло ваше решение!!!

Answer (score 2):

Тьфу, блин, после ответа решил заглянуть в `networkx.floyd_warshall`, а там же есть `predecessors in the shortest path` и `reconstruct_path`

---

Заведите матрицу такого же размера, и **при выборе  минимума** в самом внутреннем цикле Флойда-Уоршелла ([псевдокод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)) записывайте туда (в `m[i,j]`) номер вершины `k`, соответствующий текущему этапу - переменной самого внешнего цикла. Ведь внешний цикл отвечает за то, чтобы улучшить матрицу лучших путей, если использовать `k`-ю вершину (до этого она не применялась).

Таким образом, после работы алгоритма для пары вершин `a,b` мы будем знать одну из вершин `c`, через которую проходит лучший путь. Аналогично найдём внутренние вершины для пар `a,c` и `a,b`, повторим рекурсивно до нахождения полного пути.

Comment: спасибо @MBo, я понял, что вы имеете введу, но реализовать в коде не получаеться

Comment: А Вы используете networkx?

Comment: да, и Matplotlib

Comment: Ну ведь там есть reconstruct_path для этой цели, если я правильно понял

Comment: Ага, спасиб, нашел в документации

Comment: то есть мне нужно записать reconstruct_path(source=откуда, target=куда, и словарь) правильно?

Comment: Почему бы не посмотреть [пример](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall_predecessor_and_distance.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall_predecessor_and_distance) в документации?