# Python, списки, кортежи

Tags: python

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Есть список: `[0, 1, 2, 4]`. Нужно получить список кортежей `result = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)]`, где кортежи — это набор элементов (предыдущий, следующий) и т. д.

Я пробовал так:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    result = [(arr[i], arr[i+1])]
```

но выбивает ошибку:

> ```
> list index out of range
> ```

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь)

Comment: посмотрите как создается переменная `edges` в [ответе на ваш предыдущий вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116527/211923)

Comment: Списковым включением так: `[(li[i], li[i+1]) for i in range(len(li) - 1)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 4]

result = list(zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]))
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

**Объяснение**

Делаем два среза одного списка:

- первый срез с нулевого элемента по предпоследний - `0, 1, 2`.
- второй срез с первого элемента  по последний - `1, 2, 4`

Складываем их с помощью функции `zip()`, получаем:

```
lst[:-1] ->  0 1 2
             | | |
lst[1:]  ->  1 2 4
```

---

Так как функция `zip()` останавливает свою работу при исчерпании самой короткой из переданных последовательностей, можно использовать исходный список вместо первого среза. Тогда выражение может быть упрощено:

```
result = list(zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

В этом случае, схема будет такой:

```
lst      ->  0 1 2 4
             | | |
lst[1:]  ->  1 2 4   # эта последовательность закончилась первой,
                     # zip() прекращает работу.
```

Comment: спасибо большое, мне очень помогло!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 4]

result = []
for i in range(len(array) - 1):
    result += [(array[i], array[i+1])]
```

---

В функции `range()` я применил количество о 1 меньшее, чтобы `array[i+1]` не выходил за границу списка `array`.

Comment: спасибо большое, работает!!!

Comment: @Ivan, не стоит.